# jQuery - Div doesn't fit page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I've a very small issue with jQuery. I'm using the latest version of HighCharts jQuery library (http://www.highcharts.com/) to generate graphs on a project of mine. Since I don't want to provide tens of graphs all in the same page, I splitted them into tabs that open/close with slideUp and slideDown effects. Everything is all right but there's just a very small issue.

As soon as I load the page the default tab is selected correctly and I can normally see the graph. When I click on another tab, the previous one slideDown meanwhile the selected one slideUp and here comes the problem. The graph inside always always occupies 310px of page width and here's why.

```
<div style="min-width: 310px; max-width: auto; height: auto; margin: 0 auto" id="container3" data-highcharts-chart="3"></div>
```

This is the div that contains the graph and as you can see there are the attributes **min-width: 310px** and **max-width: auto**. It seems to me a glitch of jQuery in fact as soon as I resize my page the graph immediately "snaps" back to his position occupying 100% of page width. Same happens when I simply open FireBug. As soon as FireBug opens the graph "snaps" and fill the div.

Sadly I'm not able to provide a code since it's a Smarty + Jquery + PHP + MySQL project all inside a Framework and I'm not able to isolate the problem. What should I do to "refresh" or "flush" the min-width / max-width?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can try is to only render the chart once the tab has been opened for instance :

```
 $(".tab-selector").slideDown( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete. Render chart here

  });
```

A hacky solution would be to call a browser resize event in the animation complete handler which will work the same as if you were to resize the browser manually.

```
 $(".tab-selector").slideDown( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $(window).trigger('resize');
 });
```

Sorry if this does not help at all, difficult to know the exact cause of your problem without a clear running example.